# Photoshop, change canvas size ADDS to existing canvas size rather than change

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Here's me changing canvas size to 100X10 inches:
[image]

Then I click OK, and then when I go to Image > Canvas to peep the current size it shows up as 220X30 inches:

[image]

I notice that my original size was 120X20 so it appears that it's adding the original size + the changes. But why?? I want something to be 100X10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the 'relative' box checked - untick that, and your canvas will resize to 100 x 10 inches. However, you'll see a warning that some clipping will occur - if your artwork is outside the 100 x 10 area, you'll lose some of it.

What you *may* want to do instead is change the image size (Image > Image Size) to 100 x 10 - this will scale your artwork down rather than clipping the edges from the canvas.

Scaling the canvas **up** will give you more space around the edges, while scaling it **down** will trim the edges off the canvas.